# Marionette erro in geckodriver running in linux machine

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

I have the following firefox version install in a remote linux machine:
Mozilla Firefox 112.0.2 where it was installed though command: sudo apt-get install firefox
and the system installed the snap version of firefox. In the release page of geckodriver I choose the 0.31.0 version which is compatible with firefox version, but when i run my python script with selenium bot it fails while setting up webdriver. The displayed error is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Failed to read marionette port
```

i've tried several alternatives such as:
set the geckodriver path explicitly by providing the parameter `executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'` of webdriver.Firefox

set:

```
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
```

in the python script